Fetch first X rows from a sorted result in subquery
I want to select only those identifiers from a table which are contained in another subquery result and only top-2 rows must be used.
For example you can run the query on PG:
select a.rid 
from(
    values (41), (42), (43), (44)
    ) a(rid)
where a.rid in
(
select b.x
from(
    values (43), (44), (42), (41)
    ) b(x)
    order by b.x
fetch first 2 rows only
);

It should return
41
42

It works. However if I use the following query with CTE's
select rid 
from(
    values (41), (42), (43), (44)
    ) s(rid)
where rid in 
(
with recursive messages as (
    select
        rid as "root_id",
        parent.id,
        parent.sent_date
    from
        purchase_message parent
    where
        parent.id = rid
union
    select
        rid as "root_id",
        child.id,
        child.sent_date
    from
        purchase_message child
    join messages on
        child.parent_message_id = messages.id 
    ),
ordered_root_ids as (
        select
        m."root_id",
        max(m."sent_date") over (partition by m."root_id") as "maxSentDate"
    from
        messages m
            order by "maxSentDate" desc
    )
    select "root_id" from ordered_root_ids
    fetch first 2 rows only
)

it doesn't work. I get all the results
41, 42, 43, 44

Why doesn't it return only 2 results?
According to my expectations it must be only 2 results, and it must be 43 and 44 because they are the latest messages.
I don't know how to provide all the related tables because there are too many. I hope they aren't necessary. Does CTE or recursive CTE or nested query affect this? Or combination of all of them? How to modify the above query so that it sorts data in the subquery, takes 2 top rows and then they are used in the in clause of the outer query?


Does CTE or recursive CTE or nested query affect this? Or combination of all of them?

It doesn't. There's no way for limit 2 and fetch first 2 rows only to return more than just the two rows. Still, you're getting 2 rows for each value that you're checking, so it's more than enough. This:
select rid 
from(
    values (41), (42), (43), (44)
    ) s(rid)
where rid in 
(--parenthesized subexpression

Will run the parenthesized subexpression for each rid independently, like a lateral subquery, because you referenced the outer rid inside there. As a result, for each value you check, you're getting up to two matches. I'm guessing you expected to only get the 2 matches once, and that the in() would compare each value to those two.
You can move your inputs to a CTE, then reference all its rids at once from your subquery, have them all descend down the hierarchy, get sorted together then filtered down together to the top 2. Demo at db<>fiddle:
with inputs(rid) as (values (41), (42), (43), (44) )
select rid 
from inputs join
(   with recursive messages as (
        select parent.id as "root_id",
               parent.id,
               parent.sent_date
        from purchase_message parent
        where parent.id in (select rid from inputs)
        union
        select parent."root_id",
               child.id,
               child.sent_date
        from purchase_message child
        join messages parent
          on child.parent_message_id = parent.id 
        )
    select m."root_id" as rid
    from messages m
    group by m."root_id"
    order by max(m."sent_date") desc
    fetch first 2 rows only
)q using(rid);




rid




43


44



I also had to change your logic that selects the top two root_id based on the most recent sent_date in their hierarchy. Once it's allowed to operate on all input rid's, your code would keep picking 2 of the same rid:
ordered_root_ids as (
    select
        m."root_id",
        max(m."sent_date") over (partition by m."root_id") as "maxSentDate"
    from
        messages m
    order by "maxSentDate" desc
)
select "root_id" from ordered_root_ids
fetch first 2 rows only

because of your use of the window function, you'd get all rows of each hierarchy, each repeating their max(sent_date). As long as the hierarchy with the most recent sent_date has 2 or more rows in it, you will get those two, because they both have the same max(sent_date) and the same rid.

Thank you very much. You rescued me again!

Oh, right :) You're welcome again, then.

Your query seems to be corrupted, I cant execute it in your edition
It looks like it would be like this
with recursive messages as (
    select
        rid as "root_id",
        parent.id,
        parent.sent_date,
        parent_message_id
    from
        purchase_message parent
    where
        parent.id = rid
union
    select
        rid as "root_id",
        child.id,
        child.sent_date,
        child.parent_message_id
    from
        purchase_message child
    join messages on
        child.parent_message_id = messages.id 
    )
    ,ordered_root_ids as (
        select
        m."root_id" as root_id,
        max(m."sent_date") over (partition by m."root_id") as "maxSentDate"
    from
        messages m
            order by "maxSentDate" desc
    )
    select rid 
from(
    values (41), (42), (43), (44)
    ) s(rid)
where rid in 
(
    select "root_id" from ordered_root_ids
    fetch first 2 rows only
) 

And it works fine
rid|
---+
 41|
 42|

It would be better if you post your table data to understand what's wrong

The rid column in the subquery comes from the top-level, outer query, not from the purchase_message table, so this rearrangement would not work.
